# Having problem changing code color of template text in Dreamweaver 2022

Tags: colors, themes, dreamweaver

I have switched from Dreamweaver CS6 to Dreamweaver CC 2021.  CS6 allowed micro-selection of code highlighting colors; not so with 2021. The template code in 2021 is an indistinct grey on a black background, which is my preference for using the program. Please see http://artfromny.com/dwscreen.jpg

My problem is two-fold; I am relatively uneducated in code other than HTML and CSS (and far from expert there), and I have followed the Dreamweaver instructions at  https://helpx.adobe.com/il_en/dreamweaver/using/customize-code-coloring.html to no avail.

Creating a copy of Raven, which I then renamed Ruby Blue, I appended the code from my Brackets Ruby Blue to the palce in main.less in Dreamweaver which indicated that was the proper location for any additional code. I also changed every instance of the main.less file that contained the word "comment" to display in yellow; that worked correctly for regular comments but not comments that contained template code.  I was able to change the other selectors, tags, etc but could not change the template code.

The code I used to attempt to change the template comment code is below, followed by the code specifying all the colors of the theme.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Image of the screen at http://artfromny.com/dwscreen.jpg

```
.cm-templateComment, .cm-templateAttrVal {
    color: #98fb98;
}


.cm-comment {
    color: @comment;
}
.cm-number {
    color: @rb-lightblue;
}
.cm-string {
    color: @rb-orange;
}
.cm-string.cm-property {
    color: @rb-white;
}
.cm-error {
    color: @rb-red !important;
}
.cm-meta,.cm-keyword,.cm-bracket {
    color: @rb-magenta;
}
.cm-atom,.cm-link {
    color: @rb-yellow;
}
.cm-attribute,.cm-property {
    color: #66d9ef;
}
.cm-variable,.cm-variable-3,.cm-qualifier,.cm-def,.cm-operator {
    color: @rb-white;
}
.cm-variable-2,.cm-tag {
    color: @brightgreen;
}
.cm-builtin,.cm-special {
    color: #ff9d00;
}
```

thanks in advance

Art

Answer (score 0):

Resolved - I found a different copy of RubyBlue css - Theme RubyBlue Copyright (c) 2014 Eric Johnson

This file contained a better color for the template tags, so I did not pursue it any further.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).